# Q: How to handle more than one condition in a UML state machine transition

Tags: c, uml, enterprise-architect, state-machine

How do I handle more than one condition (with different boolean expressions) in a UML state machine transition (as guard)?

Example:
[image]

In this example I would like to add more than only one condition (Tries < 3) in the transition from "logging in" to "Logged In" like discribed in the note.

How to handle this UML compliant?

Comment: It seems that you want a solution with EA no ? So say it :)

Comment: You either decompose the state into multiple states, each with its own transition condition (e.g. "networkOK --> LoginPrompt") or you define it as one composite condition.

Comment: @granier That's why he tagged this question with EA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply spoken (and to focus on the needed step)

[image]

put a boolean condition like above in the `Guard`. This can be any text. You can write C-style or plain text. I'm not sure about OCL here, but that's for academic purpose anyway (my opinion).

N.B. Your diagram shows `Tries = 3` which should be a `Guard` also (i.e. `[Tries = 3]`) rather than a `Name`.

Comment: as I know OCL does not use && but and ... (why ? maybe these guys do not know C ..)

Comment: @granier Maybe they come from the Python, Pascal, COBOL or (somehow) FORTRAN front which use text instead of symbols too.

Comment: ;) Cobol: why not :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of options here:

1. Your guard condition can combine multiple checks within the '[]' - much like you were doing in the note.
2. You can have multiple transitions between the same two states, each with its own condition.
3. You can have states within states. So in your example the three states could be within a superstate of 'Normal Operation' - which you then further define in other documentation or via a note.

All of these are valid UML syntax. But note that just because something is valid doesn't mean it will be supported in your editor. For example it was many years before most of the features of sequence diagrams became available within editors...